# How do you pronounce the expression $(i|i)$?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm writing a library for translating latex into readable speech, and usually I rely on [Larry's speakeasy](http://web.efzg.hr/dok/MAT/vkojic/Larrys_speakeasy.pdf) to let me know how to read an equation.

Seeing as I could not find an answer for the following expression:

$$
k_{ii}\det \mathbf{K}(i|i)
$$

Namely, the `(i|i)` part, I need to find the best way to pronounce it. Otherwie I will be pronouncing it roughly as:

> Boldface Kay. Left Parentheses. Eye. Pipe. Eye. Right Parentheses.

If there is more than one context which would change its pronounciation, please provide it.

Comment: (That's an expression, not an equation. Equations equate things with an equals sign.)

Comment: It seems to be an inner product (or scalar product) over some vectorial space.

Comment: @Masacroso Text I grabbed it out of (I'm using it for examples): `Let $C_{i(j)}$ be the set of graphs obtained from $G$ by attaching edge
$(v_iv_j)$ to each spanning tree of $G$. Denote by $C_i=\bigcup_j
C_{i(j)}$. It is obvious that the collection of Hamiltonian cycles is a
subset of $C_i$. Note that the cardinality of $C_i$ is $k_{ii}\det
\mathbf{K}(i|i)$. Let $\wh X=\{\hat x_1,\dots,\hat x_n\}$.`